# The image is not fully displayed on the screen

Tags: html, css, asp.net

```
<div
  class="bg-image p-5 text-center mb-5 text-black"
  style="background-image: url('../images/banner.jpg'); background-size: cover;">
  <h1 class="mb-3 h2">Welcome to system</h1>

  <p>
    text
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html {
  font-size: 14px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  html {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

I'm writing an index view for a HomeController and I want only it to have a photo on the body of the page. But the photo is not completely on the sides and below the border

Comment: I'm 99% sure you just haven't overridden the default 8px margin on body to 0px. Having said that, this isn't a question with sufficient information to yield an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Bit hard to answer as you as you have not really asked a question and I don't think you have included the full code. But I think you will need to set the margins to 0 to get the image to the full width and height of the page.

Use inspect to check which element requires the margins changed, I would imagine it is the body element.

Comment: added more css code

Comment: In the future you should only include suggestions on how to solve the issue in the answer. I agree with your statement but the first part of the answer belongs in the comments below the question.